# Connectivity issues after the recent Google Play Services update

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

We have 3 games with real-time multiplayer based on Google Play Services. All 3 started to have problems since last Saturday (May 17), may be 1 day earlier. Right now players have problems with both connecting and playing 4-players games.

The situations we have seen:

As soon as 4 players are connected, 1 of them gets a message about Play Services crashed. It leaves the other 3 waiting for him, because they do not have any callbacks, for example about P2P disconnection.

Sometimes 3 players see that 4 players were auto-matched, but the 4th does not get any callbacks at all. So, 3 of them are trying to connect in vain.

Very often at least 1 player loses connection during the game. Being able to complete a 30-minutes game without losing P2P connections is a rarity now.

While we made minor updates in 2 games, 1 game was not updated since April 24, so it seems to be caused by the recent services update.

We have posted a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=117) to known issues database, but no response so far. And we get 100+ emails/day from unhappy players. Are we the only ones affected?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by increasing amount of developers, who have starred that bug, the issue affects everyone, not only some game ids.

A known workaround is to reconnect `GoogleApiClient` after disconnecting from the room.